# Find the nth Derivative of $e^{2x}\sin x\sin2x$

Tags: derivatives

I need to find the $n$-th derivative of $e^{2x}\sin x\sin2x$.
So anyway first we will devide the qustion into two parts
u and v
$$y=uv$$
$$u=e^2x$$
$$v=sinxsin2x$$
now
$$sinasinb=\dfrac{1}2[cos(a−b)−cos(a+b)]$$
then subsitute:
$$sinasinb=\dfrac{1}2e^2x[cos(1−2)x−cos(1+2)x]$$
btw $$cos(-x)=cos(x)$$
so now we get
$$sinasinb=\dfrac{1}2e^2x[cos(x)−cos(3x)]$$
so we bring the $$e^2x$$ inside
and get
$$sinasinb=\dfrac{1}2[e^2x.cos(x)−e^2x.cos(3x)]$$
now we use another formula
$$y=e^{ax}.cosx(bx+c)$$
$$yn=(a^2+b^2)^{n/2}.e^{ax}.cos(bx+c+ntan^{-1}\dfrac{b}a$$
selfnote:find the command for subscript and edit it in)

for part A:

a=2,b=1,c=0
which gives
$$\dfrac{1}2(5^\dfrac{n}2.e^{2x}.cos(x+ntan^{-1}\dfrac{1}2))$$

for part B

a=2,b=3,c=0
which gives
$$\dfrac{1}2(13^\dfrac{n}2.e^{2x}.cos(3x+ntan^{-1}\dfrac{3}2))$$

now we combine them both to get

$$\dfrac{1}2(5^\dfrac{n}2.e^{2x}.cos(x+ntan^{-1}\dfrac{1}2))-(13^\dfrac{n}2.e^{2x}.cos(3x+ntan^{-1}\dfrac{3}2))$$
if theres a way to improve my answer pls tell me

Comment: Do you need to find the $n$th derivative or the $n$th derivative at a point?

Comment: If the question is asking for general answers, then start off by finding a pattern in the derivatives. Ie. how many "derivatives" later does $\sin{x}$ and $e^x$ repeat?

Comment: Write $\sin x$ in terms of $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$

Comment: Or $\sin x\sin2x$ using the addition formulas

Comment: You can also transform the product of sine functions in this way: $\sin a \sin b=\frac12[\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)]$

Comment: There is also the [trinomial theorem](https://sahilmohnani.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/the-trinomial-theorem-and-pascals-tetrahedron/) and very similar formula for [general Leibniz rule for more than 2 factors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Use the transformation $\sin\alpha\cdot\sin\beta=-\frac{1}{2}\left[\cos(\alpha+\beta)-\cos(\alpha-\beta)\right]$.

Meanwhile, notice that $g(x)=f(x)e^{2x},g'(x)=e^{2x}(f'(x)+2f(x))$, the $n$-th derivative of the given function should be like $h^{(n)}(x)=-\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}(A\cos 3x+B\cos x+C\sin x+D\sin 3x)$. All you need to find is $A, B, C, D$.

Another acceptable method is, as @Empy2 mentioned above, using the equation below:
$$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$